# How to associate two input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]I want to store the correct answer(option) and the other 3 options as well. But for the other 3 options I will store those in database saying is_correct(column) 0/no/False. But for that, I'll have to have such logic that will figure out which radio button is for which input field. How do I bind/map a radio input field to a text input field?

I can, extract values out of these elements but can't figure out the logic.

```
<div id="option" class="form-group">
            <input type="radio" name="option" required/><input type="text" name="option_1" required/><br/><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="option" required/><input type="text" name="option_2" required/><br/><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="option" required/><input type="text" name="option_3" required/><br/><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="option" required/><input type="text" name="option_4" required/>
        </div>
```

I just can't figure out the next step! Seen similar types of posts but not so similar tbh despite the concept being same.

Comment: "is_correct"...?

Comment: If admin chooses an option to be correct. Then I'll assign that field is_correct=true/1 in database

Comment: Is this a form to create multiple choice quizes or a multiple choice quiz?

Comment: A multiple choice quiz.

Comment: Just a design suggestion: Consider storing the answer instead of boolean correctness status of the answer. You might need it later and in general its a good idea to store the results of the quiz. Inferring if the answer is correct or not based on admin setting would be still very easy. Think what would happen if admin selects wrong answer and then needs to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I really don't understand why you use radio buttons **and** a input text. In my opinion, just switch the input text to labels, or if you want the user to type the answer just give him 1 input text.

That being said, keeping the design you've made:

HTML:

```
<div id="options" class="form-group">
            <input type="radio" id="option_text" required/><input type="text" id="option_1" required/><br/><br/>
            <input type="radio" id="option_text2" required/><input type="text" id="option_2" required/><br/><br/>
            <input type="radio" id="option_text3" required/><input type="text" id="option_3" required/><br/><br/>
            <input type="radio" id="option_text4" required/><input type="text" id="option_4" required/>
            <button type="submit" id="sub">
            Press me
            </button>
</div>

<div id="output1">
</div>
<div id="output2">
</div>
<div id="output3">
</div>
<div id="output4">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#sub").on('click',function(){
let eachone=[];
    eachone[0]=$("#option_1").val();
    eachone[1]=$("#option_2").val();
    eachone[2]=$("#option_3").val();
    eachone[3]=$("#option_4").val();
        $("#output1").html(eachone[0]+" - "+$("#option_text").prop("checked"))
        $("#output2").html(eachone[1]+" - "+$("#option_text2").prop("checked"))
        $("#output3").html(eachone[2]+" - "+$("#option_text3").prop("checked"))
        $("#output4").html(eachone[3]+" - "+$("#option_text4").prop("checked"))
})
```

If you want to alter something, or test for your exact test case, here is the fiddle
[Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLg73s52/2/).
Note I'm using jQuery, just for ease of code, you can change most of the jquery references to `document.getElementById`

**Edit:**
Updated fiddle with checkboxes: [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tox82nr/)

**Edit2:**
Updated fiddle with single option checkboxes:
[Jfiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/e3ku2178/)

**Warning: the event created might break some other input type checkboxes you have in your code!**

Comment: Thanks yours worked almost the way I wanted. But the problem is, If admin accidently checks two radio buttons then he/she will have to reload the page right? Is there any solution to that?

Comment: Yes, that's expected behaviour, if you want to allow the user to untoggle buttons, use "checkbox" instead of "radio" buttons. I'll update the Jfiddle with one for checkboxes.

Comment: It's a Multiple Question Single Answer Quiz. I can't allow multiple checks in the first place.

Comment: Then you probably want a select? But to keep your design, I've added, a new javascript Event to handle the checkbox single answer.
The script disables all checkboxes on click and then check's the one you've clicked.
Check Edit2 for the fiddle.

Comment: I'll only have 4 checkboxes in this page anyway. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should use the `value` attribute of the radioButtons instead of the second input, just put the text in a span or a label :

```
  <input type="radio" id="option1" name="option" value="option1">
  <label for="option1">8</label>
```

then you can get the selected value by doing:

```
var selectedOption = null;
if (document.getElementById('option1').checked) {
  selectedOption = document.getElementById('option1').value;
}
```

After that, you can query the db to see if the selected option is correct or not.

Comment: But I have to store the options first to even think of checking whether it is correct or not

Comment: Now, I can get the value of checked radio button but how do I create a connection between the checked radio button and the immediate input field?

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of submitting the form with form data, you submit a JSON string/object? 
So, your object for question can be something like

```
{
    "question" : "How many planets orbit around the sun?",
    "options" : [{
        "name" : "1",
        "value" : "7",
        "isAnswer" : false
        }, {
        "name" : "2",
        "value" : "8",
        "isAnswer" : true
    }]
}
```

Now, what's left is to create this object when the submit button is clicked. 
To do that, you can have ids such as

```
<input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="option" required/>
<input type="text" id="text-1" required/>
```

These elements can be created dynamically, or manually if you are making the page just for a single question.

Now, when the ***button*** to submit the form, is clicked, you can run the below code which constructs a JSON object.

```
let question = {};
question.question = $("#question").val(); //Assuming you are using jQuery and id for question input box is question.
question.options = [];
for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
    let option = {};
    option.name = (i+1); //convert to ascii if you want alphabets
    option.value = $("#text-"+(i+1)).val();
    option.isAnswer = $("#radio-"+(i+1)).checked;
    question.options.push(option);
}
```

You can now send this question object to your server.

Comment: Thanks for your time